# Storyboard: Control-drag from a bar button to the Exit item

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue

So I'm working on a new tutorial from Apple (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html) and got to a point where I'm having a problem with the storyboard:

I cannot Control-drag from a UIBarButton to the Exit item in the scene dock. When I click on the Exit item the Attributes inspector says "Not Applicable".

Here is an extract of the tutorial. I am not able to post immages. For a better understanding of my problem you can see an image of the Control-drag to the Exit item at the bottom of the page.

> **To unwind back to XYZToDoListViewController**
>
> [...]
>
> To create the unwind segue, link the Cancel and Done buttons to the unwindToList: action through the Exit icon in the dock of the source view controller, XYZAddToDoItemViewController.
>
> To link buttons to the unwindToList: action
>
> - In the project navigator, select Main.storyboard.
> - On the canvas, Control-drag from the Cancel button to the Exit item in the
>   add-to-do-item scene dock.
> - [...]
> - A menu appears in the location where the drag ended. Choose unwindToList:
>   from the shortcut menu. This is the action you just added to the
>   XYZToDoListViewController.m file. This means that when the Cancel
>   button is tapped, the segue will unwind and this method will be
>   called."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can only do this if you have a method that knows how to handle these events. This method has to have the following signature structure:

```
- (IBAction)finishedDoingWhatever:(UIStoryboardSegue *)sender;
```

Note that it has to be an IBAction and that it takes the segue as an argument. Once you do that, the popup should appear from the exit icon.

Comment: I didn't know that you could do this to pop / dismiss from a storyboard.  It seems broken that you need to have a empty method implementation to get this working.

Comment: @Robert: Not necessarily. Since the argument is a UIStoryboardSegue, that instance will have a property `sourceViewController`, which refers to the view controller that you're dismissing. Any (public) data from that view controller can be used for processing in this method. It's a lot simpler than using delegation for basic presenting/dismissing.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! I accidentally used the wrong signature: - (IBAction)finishedDoingWhatever:(UIStoryboard *)sender; Now everything works as expected :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried saving the XYZToDoListViewController.m after you wrote the unwindToList method?

I just added another unwind method and it only showed up in the exit menu after saving the view controller.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! I accidentally used the wrong signature: - (IBAction)finishedDoingWhatever:(UIStoryboard *)sender; Now everything works as expected :-)