# How to use prepareForSegue for multiple Tableview Controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am having three table views A,B,C . The flow of view is like this:

table A ,click on a row --->table B, click on a row----Table C

I am using the following method to send the data from master view A to detail view B.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetailFinal"]) {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self->ListView_A indexPathForSelectedRow];
    DetailView_B *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    destViewController.detailStatements = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
}
```

and I have the same method again to send the data from detailView_B to moreDetailView_C

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetailFinal"]) {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self->DetailView_B indexPathForSelectedRow];
    More_DetailView_C *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    destViewController.detailStatements = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
}
```

I am using the modal segues instead of push. The problem is that,when I go to table B from table A, I see data in table B.

But when I go back to table B from table C, I do not see any data in table B.

The view did load method in table B is :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"the name is %@",detailStatements.name);
// here when I come from table A, name is not null

//but when I come from table C,name is null.
```

}

Is it possible to use common segue identifier for all 3 table views?

Kindly tell me the possible way to handle this?

Comment: Can you show us code which you bring to B from C. C-->B and B-->A. I think you must be creating new instance of tableView B when you are returning from C to B.

Comment: How do you go from C to B?

Comment: through navigation button in the navigation bar at top. I didnt use any code.

Comment: i just ctrl dragged the navigation button in table C to table B and made it modal segue!!! I did the same from B to A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments you need an unwind segue and not the normal segue you are using for going backwards.

This might help [Storyboard: Control-drag from a bar button to the Exit item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543324/storyboard-control-drag-from-a-bar-button-to-the-exit-item)

Or add an action to the buttons to simply dismiss the view controller.

Comment: I used an action to the button to dismiss the view controller. Glad it worked like a charm!!!! Thanks!!